# how to change the character to the one before it using ascii

Tags: python-2.7, file, ascii, caesar-cipher

I have a problem in my code.
It needs to change every character to the character before it.
The problem here is that for the file:

```
uif xiffmt po uif cvt hp spvoe boe spvoe
uif xiffmt po uif cvt hp spvoe boe spvoe
```

it needs to return:

```
the wheels on the bus goes round and round
the wheels on the bus goes round and round
```

But it returns them in one row:

```
the wheels on the bus goes round and round  the wheels on the bus goes round and round
```

How can I fix this?

```
def decode(in_file, out_file):
    try:
        f = open(in_file, 'r')
        for line in f:
            lst = list(line)
            lst2 = [chr(ord(x) - 1)  if x != ' ' else ' ' for x in lst]
            a = "".join(lst2) 
            with open('out_file.txt','a') as f2:
                f2.write(a)

    except IOError:
        print "Cant decipher' {"+in_file+"} 'due to an IO Error."
        f.close()
    finally:
        if f!=None:
            f.close()
            f2.close()
print decode( 'q4.txt', 'out_file.txt')
```

Comment: Somehow the newline character gets lost. You need to either prevent that, or add it back after you're finished with one line.

Answer (score 0):

*edit: I've just realized mine (and yours ;) ) mistake, the real answer follows*

When you are changing the charterers, you do that also for the non-printable ones - those with ascii code < 32. One of them is the newline character - `\n`, code number 10, which is replaced with tab - code 9.
The fix would be to simply skip changing all with such code number:

```
 lst2 = [chr(ord(x) - 1)  if ord(x)>32 else x for x in lst]
```

---

***Old answer***, which doesn't address the actual problem.

The `write()` method does not append a newline automatically - it writes whatever the variable value is, and is done with it.

So you should either append one yourself:

```
        with open('out_file.txt','a') as f2:
            f2.write(a + '\n')
```

or, having stored all modified lines in a list variable, dump its content using the `writelines()` method - it separates every list member by a newline.